# in RESTful how to get html and json data at once

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

I'm beginner Java Programmer.
Nowadays, I'm studying about RESTful application, like http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/
So I'm making message board for practice, and now I'm trying to get board data by number.
Just like a Stackoverflow. for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123456789
If you click this link, you can see html and the body of the board data.

**The problem is, I can only send a html or Json data. So, I can only get a html data without json or a json data without html.**

How can I handle this problem?
Of course, I can send a html file first. and then, by javascirpt, I can get a json data. but I think this is wrong way to do.

I know this a stupid question, but I really want to know how to handle this.

Comment: That is not a wrong way to do. Basically, when you need data, u hit tha api. Now when you need 2 data of different type, it is totally justified to hit 2 web api to get the data. What u don't want to make 2 calls?

Comment: @Spidi'sWeb I just wanted to check "am I doing right?", and you're right. I will change my code. Thank you for a help.

Comment: You could always check the request type too.. For the same endpoint: If the request is an Ajax request then return JSON otherwise return templated html.

Comment: I am happy that people try to search for best solutions to there problems.

Comment: @axlj I will search about  Ajax and request type. thank you.